# Multiple light sources on canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, effects

I want to place a number of light sources on a background for a game I'm making, which works great with one light source as shown below:

[image]

This is achieved by placing a .png image above everything else that becomes more transperant towards the center, like this:

[image]

Works great for one light source, but I need another approach where I can add more and move the light sources around.

[image]

I have considered drawing a similar "shadow layer" pixel by pixel for each frame, and calculate the transparency depending of the distance to each light source. However, that would probably be very slow and I'm sure there are way better solutions to this problem.

The images are just examples and each frame will have considerably more content to move around and update using requestAnimationFrame.

Is there a light weight and simple way to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

With the help of ViliusL, I came up with this masking solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/CuC5w/1/

```
// Create canvas
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 300;
canvas.height = 300;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

// Draw background
var img=document.getElementById("cat");
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);

// Create shadow canvas
var shadowCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var shadowCtx = shadowCanvas.getContext('2d');
shadowCanvas.width = canvas.width;
shadowCanvas.height = canvas.height;
document.body.appendChild(shadowCanvas);

// Make it black
shadowCtx.fillStyle= '#000';
shadowCtx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

// Turn canvas into mask
shadowCtx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";

// RadialGradient as light source #1
gradient = shadowCtx.createRadialGradient(80, 150, 0, 80, 150, 50);
gradient.addColorStop(0, "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0)");
gradient.addColorStop(1, "rgba(255, 255, 255, .1)");
shadowCtx.fillStyle = gradient;
shadowCtx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

// RadialGradient as light source #2
gradient = shadowCtx.createRadialGradient(220, 150, 0, 220, 150, 50);
gradient.addColorStop(0, "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0)");
gradient.addColorStop(1, "rgba(255, 255, 255, .1)");
shadowCtx.fillStyle = gradient;
shadowCtx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Comment: Well i have another suggestion if you're interested : see here to watch the result (especially the right candle) http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/ABfVj/

Comment: Great solution! I'll give them both a try in the actual game to see which works best.

Comment: About your 1 px issue : Be aware that, even if imho it is a mistake, the stroke of a geometry is centered, it's not topped by the geometry dimensions. So when you do ctx.arc(.,., r ,...) + ctx.stroke(); you probably mean ctx.arc(.,., r - ctx.lineWidth/2 , ...) + ctx.stroke();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way to play with light is to use the globalCompositeOperation mode 'ligther' to ligthen things, and just use globalAlpha to darken things.

First here's an image, with a cartoon lightening on the left, and a more realistic lightening on the right, but you'd rather watch the fiddle, since it's animated :
http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/ABfVj/

[image: let's play with candles and lights]

So how i did things :

To darken :
- Choose a darkening color( most likely black, but you can choose a red or another color to teint the result).
 - choose an opacity ( 0.3 seems a good start value ).
- fillRect the area you want to darken.

```
function darken(x, y, w, h, darkenColor, amount) {
    ctx.fillStyle = darkenColor;
    ctx.globalAlpha = amount;
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
}
```

To lighten :
- Choose a lightening color. Beware that this color's r,g,b will be added to the previous point's r,g,b : if you use a high value your color will get burnt.
- change the globalCompositeOperation to 'lighter'
- you might change opacity also, to have more control over the lightening.
- fillRect or arc the area you want to lighten.

If you draw several circles while in lighter mode, the results will add up, so you can choose a quite low value and draw several circles.

```
function ligthen(x, y, radius, color) {
    ctx.save();
    var rnd = 0.03 * Math.sin(1.1 * Date.now() / 1000);
    radius = radius * (1 + rnd);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter';
    ctx.fillStyle = '#0B0B00';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * π);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, radius * 0.90+rnd, 0, 2 * π);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, radius * 0.4+rnd, 0, 2 * π);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();
}
```

Notice that i added a sinusoidal variation to make the light more living.

Ligthen : another way :
You can also, while still using the 'ligther' mode, use a gradient to have a smoother effect (first one is more cartoon like, unless you draw a lot of circles.).

```
function ligthenGradient(x, y, radius) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter';
    var rnd = 0.05 * Math.sin(1.1 * Date.now() / 1000);
    radius = radius * (1 + rnd);
    var radialGradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(x, y, 0, x, y, radius);
    radialGradient.addColorStop(0.0, '#BB9');
    radialGradient.addColorStop(0.2 + rnd, '#AA8');
    radialGradient.addColorStop(0.7 + rnd, '#330');
    radialGradient.addColorStop(0.90, '#110');
    radialGradient.addColorStop(1, '#000');
    ctx.fillStyle = radialGradient;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * π);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();
}
```

i also added here a sin variation.
Rq :  creating a gradient on each draw will create garbage : store the gradient if you use a single gradient, and store them in an array if you want to animate the gradients.
If you are using the same light in several places, have a single gradient built, centered on (0,0), and translate the canvas before drawing always with this single gradient.

Rq 2 : you can use clipping to prevent some parts of the screen to be lightened (if there's an obstacle).
I added the blue circle on my example to show this.

So you might want to ligthen directly your scene with those effects, or create separately a light layer that you darken/lighten as you want before drawImage it on the screen.

There are too many scenari to discuss them here (light animated or not, clipping or not, pre-compute a light layer or not, ...)  but as far as speed is concerned, for Safari and iOS safari, the solution using rect/arc draws -either with gradient or a solid fill-  will be rocket faster than drawing an image/canvas.
On Chrome it will be quite the opposite : it's faster to draw an image than to draw each geometry when the geometry count raises.
Firefox is rather similar to Chrome for this.

Comment: This turned out to be way better for what I was doing, and also solved a lot of other issues I had. Many thanks for taking the time to put this together! I do have one small problem when moving the light around. A 1px circle/border appears at the edge of the light aura and disappears again when the animation stops. Probably just something wrong with my implementation.

Comment: Well for the 1px issue i guess i can't help without more information... but i think you'll figure this out. Glad i could help ! 
@MarkE : yes i like this effect : simple to do and amazing to watch !

Comment: I found the problem in a previous path that wasn't closed during animation. The only downside to this solution is that darker colors and blacks doesn't go any lower than zero on `darken`, but are increased above zero with `ligthen`, making everything lose contrast and look washed out. Specially in my game since I use pixelerated graphics where objects, characters and items have black outlines.

Comment: as i told in my post, there are many many possible ways to build a light effect. You can ligthen first or after you darkened, you can clip to avoid effects on some part of the screen, and you can use opacity to reduce the effect's intensity. It's all about the order in which you do things. If you want to get high contrast on cartoon images while having color shades, split the outline draw in another method, and have the outline always drawn in black with full opacity.

Answer (score 2):

1. your png should have full transparent corners and not transparent white in middle.
2. or you can draw this, but not pixel by pixel like here jsfiddle.net/pr9r7/2/

More examples: jsfiddle.net/pr9r7/3/ http://codepen.io/cwolves/pen/prvnb

Comment: This would, as far as I can see, only create a white (or colored) blob covering the background. Not an actual light source, increasing the brightness of what's below. The torch in my example wouldn't be visible beneath it. I want to achieve the result to the right here: http://imgur.com/LLRt3wW

Comment: depends on png - http://jsfiddle.net/pr9r7/3/ better? Also check this example http://codepen.io/cwolves/pen/prvnb

Comment: The codepen example was very close to the solution I just came up with! http://jsfiddle.net/CuC5w/. I'll take a closer look at that example to see if there are any improvements to be made. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Take on it:

**A.** *Don't worry about performance until you have tried it out. The Canvas is pretty darn fast at drawing.*

**B.** Rather than having a image with dark Corners and a Transparent middle. Why don't you try and make it more "IRL" and have the overall world be more Dark and let the light-source illuminate the Area?  Highlight a small area, instead of darken everything EXCEPT a small Area.

Comment: A) You are right! Only since I don't have that solution entirely figured out yet either, I figured I'll see if there's a better way before I try it out. B) This is exactly what I would like to do! I just can't figure out a way to do it without covering the background. Of course I could fade out white from the light source instead of fade in black from the edges, but that wouldn't brighten the background, only cover it. Like this (on the left): imgur.com/LLRt3wW

Comment: Well GameAlchemist seems to have a nice Solution there too ^^